# How to manipulate a Excel file on OneDrive with Python?

Tags: python, excel, sharepoint, onedrive

I am trying to manipulate a Excel file that is in a OneDrive Folder.

I am using this simple Python Code:

```
def Test():

    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(config_data['SchedulePath'])
    ws = wb.active

    ws['P6'] = "SomeTestText"
    wb.save(config_data['SchedulePath'])
    wb.close()
```

It works, it does put "SomeTestText" in Cell P6.
But after opening the Excel file and making some changes, I get this error when trying to save the file again:
[image]

With local files it works just fine.

I tried to safe the file temporarily to a local folder, then moving it back to the OneDrive, but this produces the same error.

Unfortunately I can't manipulate the file directly on the SharePoint with Python, since the authorization fails (Company Security reasons).

Edit:

Same problem using Pandas (but still openpxy1 as engine):

```
def Test():

    file_path = config_data['SchedulePath']
    df = pd.read_excel(file_path, engine='openpyxl')
    df.iloc[4, 2] = "Test"
    df.to_excel(file_path, index=False, engine='openpyxl')
```

When I use this Code, with the Macro doing the changes to the File (and saving it) it works without a problem:

```
excel = win32.DispatchEx('Excel.Application')
excel.Visible = 0  

try:
    workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(Filename=file_path)
    excel.Run(macro_name)
    workbook.Close()
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error encountered: {e}")
finally:
    excel.Quit()
    del excel
```

UPDATE 19.10.:

When I open the Excel, type something else in and then save the file, it will give me the shown error. If I then click "Discard changes" it removes what I typed in of course. If I now type it in again, and click save, it will save the file no problem.

There is no difference on how long I wait after using my Code, I tried to wait 2 hours, still the same issue.

The Problem only exist on my Device. If I use a different Device, with the same company account, everything works.

Comment: Is there anything special about the Excel file? Macros, formatting, etc?

Comment: No, for now its just an empty Excel file, only Value in it is the "SomeTestText"

Comment: Out of curiosity do you run into the same problem if the file is created entirely through `openpyxl`?

Comment: Good Idea!
But the problem is still the same, when I use     wb = openpyxl.Workbook()